# Tinymce adding shortcuts for custom styles

Tags: javascript, tinymce

In my tinymce initialization i use my predifined styles

```
style_formats : [ 
    {title : 'Date', inline : 'span', classes : 'date'},
    {title : 'Trend UP', inline : 'span', classes : 'trend_up'},
    {title : 'Trend DOWN', inline : 'span', classes : 'trend_down'},
    {title : 'Trend NO', inline : 'span', classes : 'trend_no'}
]
```

This predifined styles wraps selected content into span tag and adds specific class for it;
[image: styles example]
But now i need to add shortcuts (hotkeys) that will provide the same functionality

for that purpose i've created plugin where my hotkeys will be defined

```
(function(){

    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.MyShortcuts', {
        init : function(ed, url) {
            ed.addShortcut('ctrl+e','Format Blockquote', ['FormatBlock', false, 'blockquote'], this);
        }
    });

    // Register plugin with a short name
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('my_shortcuts', tinymce.plugins.MyShortcuts);
})();
```

And it works fine for blockquote. But i didn't find any useful information for me in [tinymce documentation](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.addShortcut) **to implement shortcuts for my custom styles**.

Can somebody help me how to implement this functionality?
I tried to do

```
ed.addShortcut('ctrl+e','Format Trend UP', ['FormatBlock', false, 'Trend UP'], this);
```

and

```
ed.addShortcut('ctrl+e','Format Trend UP', ['StylesBlock', false, 'Trend UP'], this);
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please where can i paste that code in Tinymce 3 to add shortcode to Blockquote ? I will show appreciation for your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used this link (http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/custom_formats.php) to find solution.

In addition to

```
style_formats : [ 
    {title : 'Date', inline : 'span', classes : 'date'}
]
```

I've added format to initalization:

```
formats: { mydateformat: {inline: 'span', classes : 'date'}}
```

After that code in plugin was very simple:

```
  ed.addShortcut('ctrl+alt+3', 'Date format', function(){
    ed.formatter.apply('mydateformat');
  });
```

or with some improvement

```
ed.addShortcut('ctrl+alt+3', 'Date format', ['FormatBlock', false, 'mydateformat'], this);
```