# How to add bulleted and number list keyboard Shortcut in tinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, text-editor

Please help me for adding keyboard shortcut for bullet and number list using addShortcut() function.

Ctl + N  For Number List
Ctl + R  For Bullet List

Comment: What are the shortcut you want ?

Comment: Ctl + N For Number List  and Ctl + R For Bullet List

Comment: And with a little search ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307182/tinymce-adding-shortcuts-for-custom-styles

Comment: Can you please share me block of code ?

Answer (score 1):

Here the code you need to include in your plugin:

```
  ed.addShortcut('ctrl+n', 'OrderedList', function(){
    ed.execCommand('InsertOrderedList');
  });

  ed.addShortcut('ctrl+r', 'UnorderedList', function(){
    ed.execCommand('InsertUnorderedList');
  });
```